# Insulating a steel outbuilding, first major DIY project

Tags: insulation

My parents just bought a house. My dad, a disabled vet spends most of his time in his workshop. His new workshop is a 700 sq ft steel outbuilding that has no insulation. I have a local AC company installing a 24k BTU ductless A/C to replace the pitiful window unit hes trying to cool it off with now, and i have 30 r30 bats of fiberglass insulation on order from Lowes for the roof, but i need some advice. i have been doing research on radiant barrier insulation, that its best used in between the framing and the steel paneling to prevent the transfer of heat. Obviously its too late for that since its fully built and im doing all this work myself and theres no way i would be able to deconstruct the building.
My question: Im getting the radiant barrier insulation for the 2 roll top doors, 
          1)would it still be effective inbetween the rafters before i put the fiberglass bats in
          2)if it is, should there be an air gap (some of my research says there needs to be an airgap, some says right on the bare metal)
          3)since im doing this myself, what would be the easiest, most cost effective way of attaching it since the studs are metal

Also, installing the fiberglass bats, my plan was to predrill holes in the rafters and put screws thru the plastic holding the insulation in.
          1)which would be better, plastic sheeting or housewrap so it can breath? (i live in florida so humidity is a concern) 
          2)is there a better way to do it

Im on a tight budget so hiring outside help is out of the equation, I work maintenance at a hotel so i have some technical skills, but i have never dealt with a project of this magnitude and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: cnsider a mini-split so he  gets heat also.